# Where does the term "tankie" come from?

Tags: terminology

So, I was a total bystander in a very heated discussion recently. It seemed like one of the participants was a total war-hawk regarding this Ukraine situation. The guy on the other side seemed to be a total apologist for Putin.

The war-hawk called the other person a "tankie." Both seemed to know what the term meant. And it sure seemed to be taken as an insult.

Where does the term "tankie" come from? What does it mean?

Comment: Well, I've upvoted since it's on-topic and 4 DVs seemed a bit much, but this was easy to google https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tankie

Comment: I can’t make sense of the description. “War-hawk”? Are you saying that *both* participants of the discussion were Putin supporters? Why were they arguing, then?

Comment: “War-hawk” is a person suporting a wor no meter from which side.

Comment: Did you google the term before asking? Asking probably took longer and did not result in more information.

Comment: @Trilarion  Exercise some "mind reading" and surmise why I might have asked this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Tankie" originated as a [label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tankie) for westerners who backed the Soviet Union so thoroughly that they approved of the use of tanks to crush the [Hungarian Revolution of 1956](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_Revolution_of_1956) and/or the 1968 [Prague Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague_Spring) uprising. The violent repression of those movements made it plain that the USSR was as authoritarian as the Russian Empire it had replaced, that its claims of rule by the people were lies, and that it treated all of Eastern Europe as its empire.

The analogy to present-day Russia's actions in Ukraine is pretty obvious.

Comment: Except that Russia no longer purports to be communist.

Comment: @Acccumulation: True, but there is a fraction of older left-wingers, at least in the UK, that has not adjusted to Russia's change of politics, and still support it, no matter what.